# Batch File: Create multiple scheduled tasks with multiple start times from user input

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I have a batch file that will create the 2 needed scheduled tasks.
It will prompt the user to enter a start time as required.
Using that entered time, it will create the %StartTime% for each scheduled task it created.

I need to have the 2nd task that is created to actually create a start time that is 1 minute later that what is entered by the user.

Example:
I run the script and enter a time of 15:00 for the start time.  Instead of placing this time for both tasks, I want the 2nd task to start at 15:01.

Code:

```
set /p startTime=Enter Start Time in 24 hour format (ex 14:00 for 2pm, 08:00 for 8am): 
schtasks /create /tn "Task1" /sc DAILY /st %StartTime% /tr "Task 1"
schtasks /create /tn "Task2" /sc DAILY /st %StartTime% /tr "Task 2"
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13736389/3439404)

Comment: The answer there is close, I need it to work off of the user input for the original time, that is the part I am having trouble with.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: Just instead of `"%time%"` referenced there use `"%startTime%"` and omit that _seconds_.

Comment: JosefZ - Thanks for the assistance, with a little more changes, that seemed to help get me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p startTime=Enter Start Time in 24 hour format (ex 14:00 for 2pm, 08:00 for 8am): 
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:." %%a in ("%startTime%") do (
   set timeHour=%%a
   set timeMinute=%%b
   set timeSeconds=%%c
)
rem Convert HH:MM to minutes + 1
set /A newTime=timeHour*60 + timeMinute + 1
rem Convert new time back to HH:MM
set /A timeHour=newTime/60, timeMinute=newTime%%60
rem Adjust new hour and minute
if %timeHour% lss 10 set timeHour=0%timeHour%
if %timeMinute% lss 10 set timeMinute=0%timeMinute%

schtasks /create /tn "Task1" /sc DAILY /st %StartTime% /tr "Task 1"
schtasks /create /tn "Task2" /sc DAILY /st %timeHour%:%timeMinute% /tr "Task 2"
```

After using the link provided by JosefZ, I came up with this variation of that code, thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nearly *bullet-proof* solution, now with a basic validity test of the  user's input:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
:loopStartTime
set "startTime=%time:~0,5%"
echo Need  Task Start Time in 24 hour format 
echo  (example 14:00 for 2pm, 08:00 for 8am)
set /p "startTime=Please enter Start Time (default=%StartTime: =%) "
::: test user's input and force repeat in case of extra serious error
::: e.g. mistyped `09/00` or `09%00` or `09<00` etc. instead of `09:00`
set "_val_test=%startTime: =%"
set /A "_val_test=1%_val_test::=+%" || goto :loopStartTime

::: format startTime to become a valid valid time in HH:mm (24 hours) pattern
call :addminutes startTime "%startTime: =%" 0
::: previous call with "quoted" 2nd parameter as user's input might contain
::: a valid parameter delimiter, i.e. one or more from commonly used 
::: Comma `,` Semicolon `;` Equals `=` Space ` ` Tab `     `   
echo schtasks /create /tn "Task1" /sc DAILY /st %StartTime% /tr "Task 1"

call :addminutes startTim2 %startTime% 1
echo schtasks /create /tn "Task2" /sc DAILY /st %StartTim2% /tr "Task 2"

goto :eof
:addminutes
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::: %1 (byref, obligatory) output variable name
::: %2 (byval, optional) valid time HH:mm (24 hours)
::: %3 (byval, optional) minutes to add  
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "sTime=%~2"
set /A "sPlus=100%~3%%100" 2>nul
for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=:. " %%a in ("%sTime%") do (
   set /A "timeHour=100%%a%%100" 2>nul
   set /A "timeMinute=100%%b%%100" 2>nul
)
::: Convert HH:MM to minutes + %3
set /A "newTime=(timeHour*60)+timeMinute+sPlus"
::: Convert new time back to HH:MM
set /A "timeHour=newTime/60%%24"
set /A "timeMinute=newTime%%60"
::: Adjust new hour, minute and return value
set "timeHour=00%timeHour%"
set "timeMinute=00%timeMinute%"
set "sTime=%timeHour:~-2%:%timeMinute:~-2%"
::: do not change next line
ENDLOCAL&set "%~1=%sTime%"&goto :eof
```

Note. An user can input almost anything in response to `set /P`; output from the `:addminutes` procedure always results to a valid time in HH:mm (24 hours) pattern, e.g.

- `<Enter>` results to current time, cf. initial `set "startTime=%time:~0,5%"`
- `15` results to `15:00`
- `9:9` results to `09:09`
- `any nonsens` results to `00:00`

**Edit**: more comments in the code

`:addminutes` procedure based on [Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13736389/3439404)