# How to create task with SCHTASKS to make it run some command ONCE after 30 minutes? (Windows cmd)

Tags: windows, cmd, scheduled-tasks

Hello i'm trying to create windows cmd command what creates task automatically run app after 30mins. Regarding to schtasks.exe manual there is options MINUTE and ONCE. By using minute it works perfectly but it repeats it every 30 minutes again and again and that's not what i actually looking for. example

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC MINUTE /MO 30 /TN mytask /TR c:\windows\system32\calc.exe
```

then i started to look after other approach by using option ONCE but in this case option ST (start time) is required. I need somehow find a way how to make it take automatically from current windows time and adding there 30 min. First problem i faced was *%time%* gives output of hours, minutes and miliseconds but syntax is only hours and minutes. Solved it by using *%time:~,5%*. But how to add 30 minutes to it? Because this one gives an error and its only logically because desired task time is already in past. example

```
SCHTASKS /Create /SC ONCE /ST %time:~,5% /TN mytask /TR c:\windows\system32\calc.exe
```

I found this post: [Add minutes to time in batch (using arithmetic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716978/add-minutes-to-time-in-batch-using-arithmetic) but this is not actually what i can use in this situation because to get that time+30min value need use huge code and .bat file should be involved what is not desirable i need single windows cmd command. Any suggestions?